# asp.net file upload issue; file no uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

The folder permissions are good. It doesn't give me an error. I click the upload button which calles this function below and when it's done, my uploaded file isn't there. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
protected void submitFile(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if(
            fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower().Substring(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.Length - 3) == "doc" ||
            fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower().Substring(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.Length - 4) == "docx")

            {
                if(fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength < 512000)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName);
                    filename = filename.Replace(" ", "");
                    fileUpload.SaveAs("C:/inetpub/ ------ directory --------/Data" + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded complete.";
                }
                else
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has exceded the maximum file size of 500 kb. Please ensure that the file is smaller than 500 kb and try again";
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only PDF and Microsoft Word files are accepted. Please try again.";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought so too. Sorry, I changed it.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and checked that the `SaveAs` part is actually executed? Or do you get any exceptions? Basically, could you elaborate on what you have tried?

Comment: When you debug this, at what point is the file missing?  Does it even get posted to the server?  On what line of code does the observed behavior deviate from the expected behavior and what are the relevant runtime values when it happens?

Comment: This might be an issue: `/Data" + filename`. Also, you shouldn't be using your IIS server for file upload storage.

Comment: Sorry guys. I just missed a slash after "/Data". It works. Also, CAbbott, I'm new at this. What should I use?

Comment: @Bender, I would recommend setting up a network drive somewhere that the `ASP.NET` account has access to. This way, at least if you run out of disk space, there's no impact to your web app running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should this -->("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/w4/DanyaWebReports/Data" + filename);

be this -->("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/w4/DanyaWebReports/Data/" + filename);

Comment: YES! I'm stupid. I'm also new at this. Thanks! I was wondering who put "Datatest.doc" in my application's folder... that explains a lot

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this line

```
fileUpload.SaveAs("C:/inetpub/ ------ directory --------/Data" + filename);
```

The file is being saved in the directory  ------ directory --------

For instance for file name this.jpg the file proposed by the code will be Datathis.jpg and will be saved in the folder ------ directory --------

If you want to save in the Data directory of the website try

```
fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Data")+"\\"+filename);
```